# Is there a way to overload a method in a protocol?

Tags: swift, interface, delegates, protocols, overloading

I'd like to expand the functionality of a delegate that I've been using to accept a two different types as the second parameter. When I attempt to add an overloaded method, I get two errors:

So my question is, **Is there a way to overload a method in a protocol in swift to allow different parameters?**

**Error 1**

> Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'myCellDelegate'

**Error 2**

> Cannot assign a value of type 'ViewController' to a value of type 'myCellDelegate?'

**myCellDelegate.swift**

```
protocol myCellDelegate {

    func didChangeState(# sender: SettingCell, isOn: Bool)

    func didChangeState(# sender: SettingCell, time: Int) // error
}
```

**(in ViewController.Swift)**

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, myCellDelegate {
```

**cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomSettingCell") as! SettingCell

        let section = sectionNames[0] 
        let logItem = logItems[indexPath.row] 

        cell.settingsLabel?.text = logItem.settingLabel
        cell.settingsSwitch.on = logItem.switchState

        cell.cellDelegate = self 


        return cell
    }
```

**Usage**

```
func didChangeState(#sender: SettingCell, isOn: Bool) {
            ...
}
```

Comment: The answer to the question title is yes, absolutely.  But from the body of your question, it seems like you want to do a little more than that, and the problem lies in how you’re doing it.  Can you post some more example code (i.e. how you’re implementing the class, and how you’re passing in the delegate)

Comment: updated to show more code

Comment: Have you also implemented `func didChangeState(# sender: SettingCell, time: Int)` inside `ViewController`?

Comment: You should consider generics rather than overloading.

Comment: great idea @Woodstock, I'll certainly look into that

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity how silly of me... I didn't implement the method in my view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate answer is **YES** there is a way to overload a method in a protocol, and I was pretty much there had I only listened to the error messages.

I simply forgot to implement the method in my ViewController. Although its obvious to me now, it wasn't apparent to me at the time because the method name was the same.

So the final code should look like this:

**myCellDelegate.swift**

```
protocol myCellDelegate {

    func didChangeState(# sender: SettingCell, isOn: Bool)

    func didChangeState(# sender: SettingCell, time: Int) 
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, myCellDelegate {

    func didChangeState(#sender: SettingCell, isOn: Bool) {
            ...
    }

    func didChangeState(#sender: SettingCell, time: Int) {
            ...
    }

}
```

As @woodstock suggested in the OP, this is probably a good time to use a generic type rather than an overloaded method.